# Проблема с бесконечным циклом

Tags: python

> Почему в выводе получается бесконечный цикл?
> По идее при вводе 4-го X цикл должен был завершится, но этого не происходит..
> Может я что то упустил в коде?

```
def profile (name, **db):
"""Пример регистрации на сайте"""
print(f"{name}:")

while True:
    y = input("О чём данные?: ")
    x = input("Введите данные: ")
    db[y] = x 
    if x:
        y1 = input("О чём данные?: ")
        x1 = input("Введите данные: ")
        db[y1] = x1
    elif x1:
        y2 = input("О чём данные?: ")
        x2 = input("Введите данные: ")
        db[y2] = x2 
    elif x2:
        y3 = input("О чём данные?: ")
        x3 = input("Введите данные: ")
        db[y3] = x3 
    elif x3:
        y4 = input("О чём данные?: ")
        x4 = input("Введите данные: ")
        db[y4] = x4 
    elif x4:
        print("-Введенно достаточно данных-")
        break

for key,value in db.items():
    print(f"\t{key} - {value}")


profile("Josh")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы, кажется, предполагаете что после `if True:` может выполнится  `elif True:`. Нет, в цепочке `if/elif/elif/.../elif/else` всегда срабатывает только один вариант. Что приводит к такому порядку ввода:

```
while
y, x, y1, x1
while
y, x, y2, x2
while
y, x, y3, x3
while
y, x, y4, x4
while
y, x
print
break
```

Чтобы поправить замените везде `elif` на `if`. А ещё лучше переработайте на ввод одной пары `x`, `y` в цикле до тех пор пока размер `db` не станет равен пяти.

```
while len(db) < 5:
    y = input("О чём данные?: ")
    x = input("Введите данные: ")
    db[y] = x 
print("-Введенно достаточно данных-")
```